# oath_listener() needs an interactive environment

Tags: r, google-analytics-api

Trying to run an R script in batch file, I am getting the error "oauth_listener() needs an interactive environment" and then it halts execution.

Any ideas how to fix it? In a previous post it was suggested to save the token to a static place. If it would solve the problem, can you please tell me how I could do it?
Currently my token is saved in my own folder (for me it's a "static place" but maybe I'm wrong...)

```
library(RODBC)
library("RGoogleAnalytics", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/library")
token <- Auth(client.id = "xxx", client.secret = "xxx")
setwd("C:/Users/ecom/Desktop/Myname")
save(token,file="./token_file")
```